# SUM based on another column Sign in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, hierarchy

I have two tables

Table A has only last level id(leaf_id) information along with sum_data.

```
id    sum_data
A5    40
B3    -50
C2     90
```

Table B has hierarchy information of id's and the sign to be considered for the id.
id Z has three children A2 and B2 and C2

```
id  parent id   leaf_id   level  sign
Z     NULL        A5       1      +
A2    Z           A5       2      +
A3    A2          A5       3      -
A4    A3          A5       4      +
A5    A4          A5       5      +
Z     NULL        B3       1      +
B2    Z           B3       2      -
B3    B2          B3       3      +
Z     NULL        C2       1      +
C2    Z           C2       2      +
```

I need to calculate sum_data of Z based on sign operator and the calculation follows like this:

```
id  parent id   leaf_id   level  sign   sum_data
Z     NULL        A5       1      +     -40  --(rolled up sum_data from A2* sign =-40 * +)
A2    Z           A5       2      +     -40 --(rolled up sum_data from A3* sign =-40 * +)
A3    A2          A5       3      -      -40 --(rolled up sum_data from A4* sign = 40 * -)
A4    A3          A5       4      +      +40 --(rolled up sum_data from A5)
A5    A4          A5       5      +      40   --got this from Table A
Z     NULL        B3       1      +       50 --(rolled up sum_data from B2* sign = 50 * +)
B2    Z           B3       2      -       50 --(rolled up sum_data from B3* sign = -50 * -)
B3    B2          B3       3      +      -50  -- got this from Table A
Z     NULL        C2      1       +       0   
C2     Z          C2      2     ignore    0 -- (90 comes from Table A, as sign is ignore it is 0)
```

My output should be

```
id    sum_data
Z     10     ( -40 from A5 hierarchy + 50 from B3 hierarchy + 0 from C2 hierarchy)
```

Can you please help me in deriving the sum_data in Oracle SQL code.

Comment: Hi - please can you explain why the last 2 rows in your example have sum_data = 0? C2 has a value of 90 in your first table and a "+" in your second table

Comment: @Newbee . . . I am just baffled on how things are calculated.  How does the second row, for instance, get -40?